# how to get the selected year in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using datepicker for my input name `birth_day`. And I want to calculate the age from the current year and selected year.

`current_yr - selected_yr`

but I have no idea on how can I get the selected year from date picker.

this is my code look like.

```
<script>
    function dateYear(){
        var d = new Date();
                var year = d.getFullYear();
                return year;
    }
    $(function() {
        $( "#id_birth_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

        //how can I get the selected year?
    });

</script>

<input type="text" name="birth_day" id="bd">
<input type="text" name="age" id="ag">
```

does anyone can give me an idea about my case?

any help will be appreciated ...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$(function() {
     $("#id_birth_date").datepicker({
           onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              var startDate = new Date(dateText);
              var selectedYear = startDate.getFullYear(); // selected year
           }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to utilize the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function.

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible.. after selecting date from datepicker

You will get property of datepicker1.year which will help you get year

Or

After retrieving date into string use Convert.Toint32(strDate1)-Convert.Toint32(strDate2) ;

..Try it...Otherwise post you code,...

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer has a problem: the dateText may not be parsed because it depends on text which can be customised. Below is the enhanced accurate answer. Otherwise you will end up using an undefined date object:

```
$(function() {
     $("#id_birth_date").datepicker({
           onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              var startDate = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
              var selectedYear = startDate.getFullYear(); // selected year
           }
     });
});
```