# jQuery UI datepicker validation based on the year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to get an error when the user selects the year 2016 in my calendar UI date-picker. I'm using jQuery plugins for error messages.
This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").click(function(){

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1930:2016",
            dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
        });

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("show");
    });
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group field-user-user_dob has-success">
            <label class="control" for="user-user_dob">Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="datepicker" readonly size="12">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the selected year on the datepicker using the solution written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200491/how-to-get-the-selected-year-in-datepicker?answertab=active#tab-top). After finding the date you can check that and throw an error message as well.

In another sense, you can get the total value and extract the **year** from the value (as you are defining the deatFormat). And you can through error depending on that.

Hope it helps..:)